# AWS Mysql unknown variable Warning Log

Tags: mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I upgraded AWS Aurora Mysql 5.7 to 8, but aws aurora log outputs like this.

```
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179185Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_authentication_kerberos_service_principal=mysql/private-write-instance.cq2fuqzvcb8i.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179215Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_aurora_fast_restart_caspian_enable=1'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179223Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_innodb_trx_commit_allow_data_loss=0'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179230Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_eit_enabled=1'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179238Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_authentication_kerberos_service_key_tab=/rdsdbdata/activedirectory/keytab'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179250Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_authentication_kerberos_caseins_cmp=0'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179258Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_aurora_fast_restart_enable=1'.
2024-01-19T00:24:16.179266Z 0 [Warning] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'loose_rpc_v2_enabled=1'.
```

How can I delete or solve that warning log